# Applying Multiple Filters + Write to Multiple Topics in a Loop on Kafka Streams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, kafka-producer-api

I have a requirement where I have a list of filters (where schema_field='val') and corresponding topics. I need to iterate over those list of filters and apply them, then write the filtered record value to its specific topic using KStreams. Is there a functionality to do this?

Example:

```java
synchronized (subscriberFilterRequirements) {
    Iterator<SubscriberFilterRequirements> itr = subscriberFilterRequirements.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        SubscriberFilterRequirements req = itr.next();
        log.info("*** Applying transformations on record");
        KStream<String, GenericRecord> subscriberFilteredRecord = filteredRecord;
        if (req.getPipelineSubscriptions().getFiltersql() != null && !req.getPipelineSubscriptions().getFiltersql().isEmpty()) {
            subscriberFilteredRecord = filteredRecord.filter((key, value) -> {
                String[] filter = req.getPipelineSubscriptions().getFiltersql().trim().split("=");
                return value.get(filter[0]).toString().equalsIgnoreCase(filter[1]);
            })
         }
        Schema schema = Utils.getAvroSchema(req.getPipelineSubscriptions().getSubscriberSchemaLocation(),
                    req.getPipelineSubscriptions().getSubscriberSchemaLocationType());
        GenericRecord sinkRecord = new GenericData.Record(schema);
        List<Schema.Field> schemaFieldsList = schema.getFields();
        Iterator<Schema.Field> sinkIterator = schemaFieldsList.iterator();
        subscriberFilteredRecord.map((key, value) -> {
            fillAvroRecord(sinkRecord, sinkIterator, value);
            return new KeyValue<>(key, sinkRecord);
        }).to(req.getPipelineSubscriptions().getKafkaTopic());
    }
}
```

Currently, what is happening is that, the loop's context and the KStream's context are not the same. When streaming is started, the loop executes fine the first time, i.e., KStream receives the first filter and from then on, the KStream runs like an infinite loop without taking the second filter. I want to inject the rest of the filters, one after another to be applied on the record.

Comment: Your code example should work. Of course, you might want to use a different topic name in `to()` operations. You could map each filter to the corresponding output topic first, and than apply `forEach` to filter-output-topic-pairs to have a different output topic for each filter.

Comment: Sample below:

`filteredRecord.filter((key, value) -> {
                log.info("Applying filter() for record with key... " + key.trim());
                    String[] filter = req.getPipelineSubscriptions().getFiltersql().trim().split("=");
                    return value.get(filter[0]).toString().equalsIgnoreCase(filter[1]);
                }).map((key, value) -> {
                log.info("Applying map() for record with key... " + key.trim());
                return new KeyValue<>(key, record);
            }).to(r.getKafkaTopic());`

Sorry, unable to format the code block.

Comment: I am writing to different topics. But doesn't seem to work. I have a few log messages inside the lambda functions of the map and filter. The log messages are not getting printed.

Comment: Not sure what `filteredRecord` is. I added an answer. Hope this helps. Btw: you can also update the question ;)

Comment: Ah, I missed changing the question itself, my bad. filteredRecord is of KStream<String, GenericRecord>. 

Thanks for your answer. I will try that out.

Comment: Your code looks correct to me. Not sure what you mean by "loop's context and the KStream's context are not the same" ? What do you mean by "When streaming is started, the loop executes fine the first time" -- you would execute this loop first, and only afterward build `new KafkaStreams()` and start it via `KafkaStreams#start()`

Comment: Nevermind, I wasn't thinking correctly. My code works fine. I had put logs in the wrong place (rookie mistake :( )...

Thank you very much for your help @MatthiasJ.Sax. :)

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax, I am able to add new filters and topic dynamically, but it is not reflected on the topology and neither is the data being written to the new topic. Is there a way to dynamically update the topology when I add/remove a topic-filter-map?

Comment: No. Changing the topology during runtime is not possible. After you call `KafkaStreams#start()` it will execute the topology as-is. No changes can be applied afterwards.

Comment: Hi @MatthiasJ.Sax, say if we stop the stream and restart the stream with an updated topology, it should take up the new one, right? Am I missing something here?

Comment: I guess it should -- but this turns into a new question...

Comment: I'll create a new question on this. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have 3 filters predicates `p1`, `p2`, and `p3` you can do:

```java
KStream stream = ...
stream.filter(p1).to("output-1");
stream.filter(p2).to("output-2");
stream.filter(p3).to("output-3");

// or as a loop
Predicate[] predicate = new Predicate[]{p1,p2,p3};
String[] outputTopic = new String[]{"output-1","output-2","output-3"};
for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    stream.filter(predicate[i]).to(outputTopic[i]);
}
```

This should also work via `foreach()` and a lambda expression, if you have a collection of predicate-outputTopic-pairs.

Comment: When I try something like this, it is not taking up other filters. Only first filter seems to be getting applied.

Comment: Also the number of output topics is not fixed. They can vary anytime.

Comment: Can you share your current code in the question? Can you also post what `Topology#describe()` prints? "Also the number of output topics is not fixed." -- do you mean during runtime? This would not be supported. The program cannot be changed during execution. Maybe you could build something more dynamic via Processor API and using dynamic routing in `to()`. Not 100% sure if this would work

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to use `branch` method on `KStream` with multiple predicates (filters) like the following:

```
Predicate<Object, String>[] branchingPredicates = ...;
KStream<Object, String>[] branchingStreams = kStream.branch(branchingPredicates);

for (int branchingIndex = 0; branchingIndex < branchingStreams.length; branchingIndex++) {
    branchingStreams[branchingIndex].map((k,v) -> { ... }).to(specificKafkaTopic);
}
```

Comment: Using `branch()` each record will be sent to exactly one output stream -- it seems, that the question implies that the input stream should be "broadcasted" to be filtered multiple times on different conditions.

Comment: That is correct, branch will do a "first-match". I need to apply all filters to all the records.